# Does apple review apps during the holiday break?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I had assumed they wouldn't be reviewing apps during this Dec 22-29 break (ARGH!) but on appreviewtimes.com there have been several postings both today and yesterday.

Does anyone know if they still review apps? iTunes connect is supposed to be shut down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunes connect is shut down for the holidays. Just because there are new posting on appreviewtimes.com doesn't necessarily mean the apps were just reviewed. Could be from the weekend.

Comment: For the record they don't shut down completely. I've gotten a call from Apple during the shut down period informing me one of my apps were under review after it received some reports from users. The reports had no ground and I was notified the next day that my app would remain live. This was from the app review department in Houston. While on the phone I asked them saying "I thought you shut down for holidays" and they explained they stay open with a smaller team to review big name apps (probably like Facebook/Twitter/Instagram or something).

Answer (score 2):

This is what apple wrote in the mail do developers:

> As a reminder, from Monday, December 22, through Monday, December 29, 2014, iTunes Connect, Application Loader, and iTunes Connect for iOS won’t be available.
>
> During this time, you won’t be able to submit new apps, app updates, or In-App Purchases. You also won’t be able to access iTunes Connect or make changes to TestFlight Beta Testing

Comment: Since it's that time of year again: Does that mean that if I submit an app before December 22, they will still review it during that time, or they will take a break from reviewing? What's your experience?

Comment: @Alex I think they will, but untill now I didn't receive a notification about it.

Comment: Thanks! I will post if I find out. As of today, my app is still Waiting For Review.

Comment: @Alex At this time, I still haven't received any mail from Apple that iTunes Connect, Application Loader and/or iTunes Connect for iOS will shut down during the holidays.

Comment: For future people finding this question: It appears that, no, they don't review apps during the holiday break.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, although they don't review apps, TestFlight is still working.

Answer (score -1):

No Apple doesn't review apps in Christmas vacation. From Apple's [Developer News and Update site](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12082104a):

> **iTunes Connect Holiday Shutdown**
>
> *December 8, 2014*
>
> As a reminder, iTunes Connect will shut down December 22-29 for the winter holidays. If you plan to schedule app releases or price changes to take place during this time, make sure these changes are scheduled, submitted, and approved by December 18. Users who are currently testing or have been invited to test your pre-release apps with TestFlight will not be affected. Sales and Trends reports will also remain available through the Autoingestion tool.